# File module issues with excel format

Tags: python, excel

My goal is to write result into single excel file, here is simple code that I tried:

```
import numpy_financial as npf
Present = 2000
period = 20
rate = 0.12
pmt = abs(npf.pmt(rate/12,period*12,Present))
print(pmt) 
import csv
file = open("Result.xlsx",'w')
file = csv.writer(file)
file.writerow([pmt])
```

As  an outcome, `Result.xlsx` was created, but  I can't open it. If  I change `xlsx` extension to `csv`, then it works fine. I know that there is another library called `xlsxwriter`, but just for shake of curiosity, does `csv` module supports xlsx-extensions?

Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect) module does not support `xlsx` extensions. Here is a quote from the documentation I linked:

> The csv module implements classes to read and write tabular data in
> CSV format

The documentation **does not** mention support for writing `xlsx`.